# javascript on document.location.search change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to do something like this: `$(window).on("hashchange", doSomething);` but detect `document.location.search` change?

Answer (score 2):

This was already asked in [On - window.location.hash - change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change). In a nutshell, there is no perfectly clean way to do this in JavaScript; you would need to be checking the location every now and then. Some frameworks and libraries will give you a nice abstraction layer over this but internally, they just keep polling the location.

Unfortunately, Lucas' answer is incorrect - you can use the JavaScript History API to modify the current URL without reloading the page.

Comment: @dmitrymar is not trying to change the URL without reloading. Instead, he is trying to detect a change due to a user's action, in which case the History API would be useless.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone realise this is a quality answer? You CAN change the search param WITHOUT reloading the page...

Answer (score 1):

The `hash` and the `search` tag are having different implementation. When the search string got changes the whole page got reloaded but not in the case of `hash`. So if you want to do some processing on href change then you can use the `onbeforeunload` event handler.

You can use the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event to trigger your code to run prior to navigation... If you need something more specific (e.g., only navigations initiated in your code), then I recommend that you factor out code changing window.location into a separate function, and add a hook for your custom logic.

For better understanding you may want to look at Ben Nadel's [post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-binding-events-to-non-dom-objects-with-jquery.htm) in regard to doing this, it may be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Differently from what happens with hash, if your search value changes due to a user's action, your page will get reloaded. Therefore, your option would be to use the onbeforeunload event:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp