# Detect non-programmatic url hash changes

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm using window.onhashchange to detect browser hash changes. But is there a way to only trigger the callback if the hash was changed in a non-programmatic way?

I am not asking how to use onhashchange. I am trying to avoid triggering it when I set the hash programmatically.

Basically, I want to do something similar to:

```
window.onhashchange = () => { /* ... */ };
```

But I don't want the callback to trigger if the code did the following:

```
window.location.hash = 'hello-world';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On - window.location.hash - change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Comment: Not the same question.

Comment: Have you solved it? Lately so became place that doesn't give answers to hard questions. Can you at least tell me how you solved it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it by simply setting a flag, which seems like a hack, but given JavaScript execution environments are single-threaded, should work fine.