# Grab #id from the URL in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a URL like this `http://localhost/sites/fh/index.php#second`. I want to fetch the id from the URL end and store it in a variable container to check in if else statement in jquery. How can I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On - window.location.hash - Change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window is a global javascript object,

You use window.location.hash to get the hash value, it will return null if there is no hash present.

```
var hashValue=window.location.hash;
console.log(hashValue);
```

Comment: can you explain further with a little more of the code?

Comment: @ShubhamJha Updated

Comment: Thanks... and how can I change the URL #id when I scroll down or up to load a particular ID section? Example: when I scroll down to `<div id="second"></div>` then the URL should change to #second automatically and the same when I scroll up.. can u give a different answer for that?