# Link with hash : how to always navigate

Tags: javascript, html

On the footer of the website I'm working on, I have links to different pages, and in one case, 2 links to the same page with a different hash in the url ,like this :

```
<a href="http://example.com/mypage#test>Test</a>
<a href="http://example.com/mypage#test2>Test2</a>
```

These hashes are not true anchors, they reflect some actions the user takes (namely showing/hiding some content).
If I come from another page, I navigate without any problem. However, if I am already on "mypage", then the hash changes, but nothing happens. The browser detects and anchor change and thus tries to navigate to the anchor.
That's fair enough, but **I want my user to be actually redirected** to "http://example.com/mypage#test2", as if he copy-pasted it himself in the address bar. How can I achieve that ?

I could use the hashchange event but it would make it complicated to manage the rest of the javascript, so I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very simple solution if you are using jQuery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    //code
});
```

Check out this: [On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) MDN documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [location.hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property of the window object to find out what the anchor is. To detect a change in the hash, with plain javascript, just use the [onhashchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp) event.

```
window.onhashchange = new function() {
    window.location.replace("http://example.com/mypage" + window.location.hash);
});
```