# Showing content based on a URL Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have links that lead to another page with different contents.

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="/services#item1" class="menu-btn">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/services#item2" class="menu-btn">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/services#item3" class="menu-btn">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This the code on the `/services` page:

```
<div class="menu-content item-1">Content item 1</div>
<div class="menu-content item-2">Content item 2</div>
<div class="menu-content item-3">Content item 3</div>
```

I found the bellow JS, but it works only when clicking on the anchor link on the same page.

```
var $content = $('.menu-content');

function showContent(type) {
$content.hide().filter('.' + type).show();
}

$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
   showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

I need is to display only the content related to the anchor link when load the `/services` page.

Comment: Thats because its happening on menu click, you need to have showContent fired on page load

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Comment: Add `$(function() {  showContent(location.hash.slice(1)); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you change the page on websites ( not single page apps ) , javascript ' forgets ' what you have done before.

So for your logic to work it can't be inside a click event which happened on another page. It should be inside a document.ready or window.onload function.

You can use `location.hash` to get the `#` anchor from your url.

In the below example i changed the `location.hash` value to show you that the solution works. You can skip that first line and just use the next ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  location.hash = "item1"; // skip this
  const myHash = location.hash.substr(1)
  $('.menu-content').hide().filter(`.${myHash}`).show();
  // or use : $('.menu-content').not(`.${myHash}`).hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-content item1">Item 1</div>
<div class="menu-content item2">Item 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very clear and works perfect ! just a question : Can this code works if `item1` is an ID and not a class, I mean : `<div class="menu-content" id="item1">Item 1</div>` ?

Comment: Yes. It's much more simple then. Use the `location.hash` directly in the filter 
``$('.menu-content').hide().filter(location.hash).show();`` and you can skip the `substr` part

Comment: it's works when the hash on the URL `#item-x` is a dynamic value ?
example : the URL is : `http://www.example.com/service#c2523` and the content is : `<div class="menu-content" id="c2523">Content here</div>`. I tried it on my site and not seems to be works if the hash change dynamically.

Comment: When does the `hash` change ? before entering the page ? is the hash the same as the id of the element ?

Comment: 1. I mean I have dynamic hash not standard, it change from page to another, it's not always `item-1` it can be `c-1252` or `a-5652` ... etc, depending on the id of the elements in the page.
2. yes, the hash is the same as the id of the element.

Comment: Yes. It should work. But as i said in the answer and the code you need to skip the `location.hash = "item1"; ` . Don't use/write it in your code. I used it only for example purposes. THe rest of the code should be the same.

Comment: as you see in my example the JS hide all elements and don't show to element related to the hash https://ibb.co/gRHLpDZ

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the change in the #comment106052682_59966314. Now it's works perfect! thanks

Comment: glad i could help. CHEERS